# Weird C# behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know how to desribe this problem, but my issue is,
that my function "Pathfinder" somehow changes the data of my int[,] matrix.
Is there a way of preventing this without changing my Pathfinder function?

a bit of my code:

```
int z = 0;
AStarPathfinding = GetComponent<AStarPathfinding>();
foreach (Vector2Int target in targets)
{
    Debug.Log(matrix[0, 1].ToString() + " " + z.ToString());
    AStarPathfinding.Pathfinder(matrix, playerCords, range, target, path, targets, z);
    Debug.Log(matrix[0, 1].ToString() + " " + z.ToString());
    z++;
}
```

without

```
AStarPathfinding.Pathfinder(matrix, playerCords, range, target, path, targets, z);
```

I get the console output I want:

```
20
20
21
21
22
22
```

But with that function, I get this output:

```
20
20
21
41
42
42
```

I know that has something to do with the behaviour of functions in c#, but I don't know what it is and how to prevent it.
Please help me (;

Comment: @Jawad Are you sure OP is using that implementation?

Comment: You really should change your `Pathfinder` method to not change your data. It also looks like a `static` method and it should probably be a class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the output that you are getting `AStarPathfinding.Pathfinder` is indeed changing the matrix. This is just a thing that methods can do to reference types, or value types passed with the `ref` modifier. This is because those parameters are passed by reference, so the callee and caller are actually dealing with the same object. Some methods do this, others don't, and `AStarPathfinding.Pathfinder` just so happens to be one of the former.

It sounds like you can't change the implementation, so the best thing you can do is to pass a copy of the matrix. One way to do this is:

```
AStarPathfinding.Pathfinder((int[,])matrix.Clone(), playerCords, range, target, path, targets, z);
```